# Are all boost converters isolated?

Tags: electrical-engineering, electrical

I have a few boost converters(3-6V to 40,000V) and I want to connect them serially. [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07T3XDMH8)
In order for them to be connected, they have to be isolated. Is there any way to check that? If they aren't isolated is there a way to make them isolated?

Comment: Boost converters do not have to be isolated. You can tell just by Googling images of boost converters circuits. Measure the resistance between the output ground and input ground pin to find out if they are. If they are not isolated, there is nothing reasonable you can do.

Comment: No, I need them to be isolated so I can connect multiple in series. And when I get the resistance, what should be the value?

Comment: The resistance value should be very high if isolated because that's what isolated means. They should not be the same node.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but from the link, is there any way you could tell me if it is isolated or not?

Comment: Can't tell from look at it.

Comment: Is 10 ohms a good amount

Comment: That's far, far too low to be isolated (though it's about ten times higher than what I would expect if it were unisolated).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't measure it correctly, the resistance was 320,000 ohms. Is that even possible?

Comment: If that is what it is, then that's more on the isolated end but still a lot lower than what I would like to see for a low voltage converter. At 40kV, it's probably not enough. 100mA can flow through that at 40kV.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried 2 in series and totally it made 80,000 volts